# QEMU stuck cursor

Tags: qemu, macos, cursor

I am running a MacOS machine on QEMU, and the cursor has remained stuck, and won't respond at all. Also there are two arrows (my Windows cursor and the QEMU cursor). My Windows cursor moves freely, but can't do anything in the QEMU windows.

[image]

Comment: Hi, it could be more simple to think over the problem, if you were written the configuration parameter concerning the cursor. Just kvm or `-usb -usb-tablet` or usb mouse given by vendor/product. In general: Apple macOS is a bit sensitive to mouse emulation. I recommend to give the separated USB mouse to VM with: ` -usb -device usb-host,vendorid=0x046d,productid=0xc077` (my Logitech mouse) parmetr. Good behavior of any mouse depends on correct kext or _hackintosh_ tools. The most real behavior you can expect with use of passthrough one complete USB controller PCI card.